# What is my reward for Do It Yourself Fishing?

Tags: no-one-lives-in-heaven

In [No-one Lives In Heaven](https://www.gog.com/game/no_one_lives_in_heaven) I have completed a quest called "Do It Yourself Fishing" for an unnamed NPC. I used a pickaxe to mine some rocks and give them to the NPC. I was expecting a reward of a fishing rod, or a recipe to make one, but I don't seem to have anything, and I can't get him to repeat what he said when I completed the quest.

What is the reward for this quest, and how to I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fishing rod recipe is not visible until you dig the field for the alchemist/magician/witch NPC. Once you dig her field she rewards you with a recipe book. All recipes that you have earned appear there, and you can then make them.